# Can Ubuntu mobile application development be done in Windows?

Tags: ubuntu

I came through [Ubuntu mobile development](http://developer.ubuntu.com/) but I could not find how to develop applications for it in Windows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu for Phones or Ubuntu for Android here?  They are two different products with two different ways of working.  There is no such thing as "Ubuntu mobile."

Comment: @Charles I am talking about Ubuntu on phones.

Comment: whats the difference between the two ? `Ubuntu for Phones and Ubuntu for Android`

Comment: Can you please suggest some tutorial? little less resource floating around...i am an ios developer but stuck on ubuntu mobile apps